# Connecting windows CE device to a database at server using its ip address

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce, lan

I have a windows CE device and I want to connect it to a database located at a pc, both are in local network (wireless). IP address of pc and path of database on pc is known. How can I connect to the database (sdf) from my CE device using sql CE with IP address or any other option if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to a SQL Server Compact SDF file on your PC directly, you must expose access to the SDF file on the PC via a web service or similar, for example a WCF data service.

Alternatively you can copy the file fro the dektop to your device if you connect via ActiveSync, and manipulate on the device, then copy back. But this can be brittle

Comment: Now I'm able to connect to a mdf file using ip address. Is there a way to make it user friendly? Something like using SqlDataSourceEnumerator? Have a win CE 6.0 device